# conda: find out last time an environment was used (activated)

Tags: anaconda, conda

Is it possible to find out when a specific conda environment was used, i.e., activated, the last time? How?

Background info: The idea is to sort the environments by their last use date and this way find out which one could be removed.

Comment: Did you perhaps found a way to do this? I have the exact same use-case.